# Unable to access Session

Tags: java, http, session, servlets, zk

```
public class MyClass{

private String shared;

public String mySharedFun() {
    `Session session = Sessions.getCurrent();`
}
```

I am getting Http "session" null in above case, do I need to implement any interface.

Comment: how did you implement `Sessions.getCurrent()` ?

Comment: Is this httpSession or hibernate Session ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi I din't get what u meant by above comment, can u pls ellaborate.

Comment: @mprabhat it's an httpSession.

Comment: show your Sessions.getCurrent() code

Comment: How are you calling your `mySharedFun()` method? If it is being called from a working thread ZK's `Sessions.getcurrent()` will return null as per its javadocs http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/6.0.0/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/Sessions.html#getCurrent()

Comment: @kachhalimbu in that case is there any way to access Session in Working thread?

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Mind Reader](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128551)

Comment: HttpSession is not thread-safe so generally not a good idea to access it in working thread (or if you can use synchronized to protect it). why not pass the information explicitly to this working thread instead of through session? Use ThreadLocal maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works if it is running in a ZK event handler:

```
    SimpleSession s = (SimpleSession) Executions.getCurrent().getDesktop().getSession();
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) s.getNativeSession();
```

It seems hard to get at the actual http session but its not something which you normally do when you are experienced with working with ZK. The more natural place to put your data is in the ZK implicit scope objects such as desktopScope or sessionScope which are just java.util.Map.

Here is why: a user might open two urls to your site in two browser tabs to be able to work with two orders at once. Each open url will create a zk desktop. In each tab the user clicks on things, the event handlers (user mouse clicks) should work with the business data in the desktop that the event handler is running within. If you put the business data in the http session it is global to that user; any user with two browser tabs open at once trying to do two jobs at once will have one browser tab corrupting the work they are doing in the other. If you really mean for something to be global to the user put it in the sessionScope. Things are actually held in a map within the http session.

The basic concepts page of the documentation introduces such ideas at http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Guide/Fundamental%20ZK/Basic%20Concepts/Page%20and%20Desktop which has links through to the other implicit objects such as requestScope, componentScope, pageScope, spaceScope ("ID space").

Scopes such as requestScope you would typically not use as ZK event handling abstracts you away from the ajax requests; have the events manipulate the desktopScope. This seems all very unnatural when you come from a Http request/session world but ZK is about doing event driven programming with Events fired on Components which are in a Desktop; so I stick with componentScope, desktopScope and sessionScope which are "natural" when working with ZK.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that Session class is taken from ZK. Right way how to obtain the session is
`Executions.getCurrent().getSession();`

Comment: Executions.getCurrent() will return current execution only if his code is calling it in ZK Event thread(handler)

Comment: yes @kachhalimbu I tried and got null for Executions.getCurrent(). can you please answer, it with an example.

Answer (score 0):

pass the request to your method . then HttpSession session = (HttpSession)request.getSession(); will give you the session.
if there is no session then it will create you a session.
If dont need the new session to be created then if(session.isNew()) will let you know if at all there is a current session or not.